# Generate a schema.json with graphql-ruby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-ruby

How can I generate a schema.json like the code in the links?

https://github.com/exAspArk/graphql-on-rails/blob/master/schema.json
https://github.com/Shopify/graphql-js-client/blob/master/schema.json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know if there is anyone who wants to know about this. 
But apparently, you can do it with `GraphQL::RakeTask`.
I'll leave some links here as well.

https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/1.9.3/GraphQL/RakeTask#invoking-the-task-from-ruby
https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/lib/graphql/rake_task.rb